# BeanCreationException after restart computer/IntelliJ

Tags: spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

I'm currently learning Spring & Hibernate with IntelliJ, I found the following error message after I reboot my computer even the code is working totally fine before the reboot, Could you please give me any hints to solve that.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'categoryDaoImpl': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.teamtreehouse.giflib.dao.CategoryDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [com/teamtreehouse/giflib/config/DataConfig.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to
>   obtain JDBC Connection

I created a configuration looks like this, and the categoryDaoImpl is using this sessionFactory,

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("app.properties")

public class DataConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
    Resource config = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(config);
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("giflib.entity.package"));     //Externalization
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();

    //Set driver class name
    ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("giflib.db.driver"));

    //Set URL
    ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("giflib.db.url"));

    //Set username & password
    ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("giflib.db.username"));
    ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("giflib.db.password"));

    return ds;
}
```

}

and the classpath resource,

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Set naming strategy -->
    <property name="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy">org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl</property>

    <!-- Update the database schema (structure) on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
</session-factory>
```

app.properties

```
# Hash salt for shortened URLs
giflib.hash.salt = xOBtdmJZxRcz^jkkyHfkrkT1*02bJUn+YQts0*xCeka%cGHCN1fjaC*faFtY

#Package where our entities (models) are located
giflib.entity.package = com.teamtreehouse.giflib.model

#Details for our datasource
giflib.db.driver = org.h2.Driver
giflib.db.url = jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/data/test
giflib.db.username = sa
giflib.db.password =
```

Answer (score 0):

You must of had some working H2 instance in memory.  The error is telling you that you can not get a database connection.  I think you maybe overriding your data source connection properties.  If you are using springboot, you do not need to define the sessionFactoy or dataSource beans.  If you are not using springboot, you should be, no need to learn old stuff unless you are getting paid for it.  You also do not need an xml hibernate-configuration properties file.

Try just using your application.properties file.

Note:

This is an application.yml example, but you can covert to application.properties by using the path of each yaml property.  Look up yaml, it is nice for properties and a good thing to learn.

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
# Set here configurations for the database connection
spring:
  datasource:
# h2 in memory database will be destroyed on app shutdown
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:YOUR_DATABASE_NAME;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    platform: h2
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password:
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
# Show or not log for each sql query
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
          use_sql_comments: true
          format_sql: true
```

Add a JPA @Configuration class, but you don't need to define any beans, springboot will do it for you.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({"com.teamtreehouse.giflib.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("ccom.teamtreehouse.giflib.repository")
public class JpaConfig {
   // You don't need to do any thing here atm.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I figure out that if I work with the local H2 database rather than using TCP, it is working now. You mentioned old stuff, do you have any recommendation for learning Java Spring, as I just start learning this in a online course website called teamtreehouse.